# Javascript: Check for value of CSS selector and replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the following jquery to inject CSS styles into a `<style id="customizer-preview">` tag in the `<head>`:

```
wp.customize( 'site_title_color', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        if ( $( '#customizer-preview .site-title' ).length > 0 ) {
             $( '#customizer-preview .site-title' ).remove();
        }
        $( '#customizer-preview' ).append( '.site-title { color: ' + newval + ' ; }' );
    } );
} );
```

It works fine, except the previously entered values are not being removed and the new values are just being added, cluttering up the CSS. Lines 3-5 are the problem. Basically I'm trying to check to see if there is already a value assigned to the selector `.site-title`. If there is, clear it and replace it with the new value.

Comment: Use `$(selector).html(...)` instead

Comment: `classList.toggle()` might help here.

Comment: @jmargolisvt do you have an example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle

Comment: @jmargolisvt Unfortunately I don't think this is going to work because I'm going to be adding (or appending) other elements to the style tag in the same way. I just need to be able to remove the previous CSS for each selector upon change of the new value.

Comment: You can manipulate `classList` like you would any other array.  Overall, you should change your approach so you aren't adding and removing elements all the time.  Just change the classes, whether it's `classList` directly or some jQuery method.

Comment: @Olian04 you were right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Olian04, I replaced `.append` with `.html`:

```
wp.customize( 'site_title_color', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $( '#customizer-preview' ).html( '.site-title { color: ' + newval + ' ; }' );
    } );
} );
```

This made lines 3-5 from the question unnecessary.